# Simplify multiple filters

Tags: forms, design-patterns, filter

I'm working on a UI that requires the filtering of multiple metrics, with each metric requiring the ability to sort and apply min/max values. Here's the solution I came up with. I've been told it looks too complicated. Could it be done better and/or more simply?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you have a 'sort' function ("Descending") in with your 'filters' but moving that to the table of results would leave you with only three fields per filter.

Based on the criteria in your sketch, I'm not sure you could 'simplify' it any further.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a change to the layout as such, but I'd consider a bit more grouping between the rows of filters to help break it up and stop it coming across as a daunting matrix of form controls.

Either banded rows, or even just a bit more vertical space between each row would help - whichever is more appropriate to your platform.